# Хостинг для ajax  запросов

Tags: ajax, производительность, хостинг

Название достаточно странное, но вот столкнулся с проблемой, делал на локальном компьютере сайт с ajax запросами , все было хорошо.

Вот разработка дошла к концу и нужно загружать на хостинг, естественно я загрузил, но увидел немного не то что хотел.

AJAX запросы отправлялить но вот ответа нужно было подождать..

Понял что это жутко не удобно упал в отчаяние, ведь делал довольно долго сайт, а когда дошел до финала, тут такое..

Возможно вы меня проконсультируете и расскажите как можно это одолеть?

Какой хост брать что бы все работало достаточно быстро?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - на многих сайтах дают возможность тестирования, причем очень часто бесплатного. Но можно взять обычный ping и потестировать задержки. Но только тестируйте с целевых мест, где будут Ваши пользователи.

Второе - посмотрите на объем Ваших AJAX. Может там мегабайты данных. И это будет не быстро. Поэтому, откройте консоль в браузере (например, в хроме - F12 или Ctrl+Shift+J) и:

- Посмотрите размеры и количество запросов. Возможно, некоторые запросы можно объединить в один.
- Посмотрите, нет ли дубликатов данных. Может один и тот же запрос исполняется дважды.
- Посмотрите, нет ли лишних AJAX. Возможно, что то можно прямо в страницу вставить.
- Возможно, некоторые AJAX статичны или изменяются редко. Кешировать по полной! Но аккуратно.
- gzip. При правильной настройке, все будет делать за Вас браузер и вебсервер, прозрачно сжимая данные, а нагрузка на процессор будет небольшой.

Comment: VPS идеально подошел, а код был протестирован заранее на локальном компьютере, но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 0):

http://ru.hetzner.de/ - там быстро

Comment: для такого сайта брать только VPS или сервер?!